# Can't install Apache2 on Raspbian

Tags: apache2, raspbian, raspberry-pi2, owncloud

I'm trying to install Apache2 on my Raspberry Pi running Raspbian so I could run OwnCloud using ***sudo apt-get install apache2***. When I try to install it, I keep getting [this error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8Ym96.png):

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 apache2 : Depends: apache2-bin (= 2.4.10-10+deb8u4) but it is not going to be installed
           Depends: apache2-utils (>= 2.4) but it is not going to be installed
           Depends: apache2-data (= 2.4.10-10+deb8u4) but it is not going to be installed
           Recommends: ssl-cert but it is not going to be installed
 mysql-server : Depends: mysql-server-5.5 but it is not going to be installed
E: Unmet dependencies. Try 'apt-get -f install' with no packages (or specify a solution).

***sudo apt-get -f install apache2*** will not work either. I updated Raspbian and also made a clean install of Raspbian, but I still have the same error. I'm pretty new to programming and only know Arduino and a bit of Swift, so thanks for the help!

Comment: Please edit your posts and paste the error log you're getting from the terminal. Also re-read the line "You might want to run `apt-get -f install` to correct these:"

Comment: I tried to use apt-get -f install but it didn't work either. I'll paste the error log in!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This process worked for me on a RPi 2 with NOOBS:

First, restore RPi to factory settings by holding down the space key when it boots and selecting Raspbian from the menu.

Then:

```
sudo apt-get update

sudo apt-get upgrade

sudo apt-get install apache2 -y
```